# Roblox studio error "Attempt to concatenate string with Instance"

Tags: lua, roblox

So I got this error and I cant seem to fix it.
Can anyone tell me how to fix it?
The error was : Attempt to concatenate string with Instance.
[Image of the full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBZtP.png)

The function:

```
function chatfunc(msg) -- < error line 523
coroutine.wrap(function()
    local amountsofchats = 0
    for i,v in pairs(workspace:GetChildren()) do
        if v.Name == "amogus"..plr then
            amountsofchats += 1
        end
    end
    if amountsofchats >= 5 then
        return
    end
    for i,v in pairs(workspace:GetChildren()) do
        if v.Name == "amogus"..plr then
            v.StudsOffset += Vector3.new(0,2,0)
        end
    end
    ...
```

The second error thing:

```
game:GetService("Players")[Username].Chatted:Connect(function(msg)
local msg,Message_ = msg,msg
if string.sub(msg,1,3) == "/e " then
    msg = string.sub(msg,4)
end
chatfunc(msg) -- < error line 717
```

end)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because are you trying to concat a string with an instance for example `"string" .. Instance.new("Part")`.

Now since you didnt give any lines numbers with your code, I am assuming `"amogus"..plr` is what causes the error, since plr is here an instance you probably ment to do `"amogus"..plr.Name` which is concatting two strings

Also

i do not recommend doing this at all `game:GetService("Players")[Username]` if the user has name which is a property of Players service u will get the property instead of the player. for example if you have the username `MaxPlayers` that will return a number and not the player with that name thus your code will error. So I recommend doing `game:GetService("Players"):FindFirstChild(Username)`

Comment: Sorry for not including the error lines in the first place. I edited the question above to include the error lines ^^^

Comment: @Ywly23 Since you are using a coroutine.wrap to spawn a new thread it basically consume the stacktrace from the code that is executed with it, recommend using the new [task library](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/lua-docs/task) which does have proper stacktraces, atm the stacktrace ends at the coroutine.wrap thus i can't exactly tell which line causes the error, but I am steadfast that my assumption is correct. So try it